# Build Linux kernel with prebuilt object files

Tags: linux-kernel, llvm

I am trying to build the files in the kernel `mm/` directory with a personalized `LLVM` compiler, then link them together with the rest of the kernel to get a bootable kernel. I extracted the exact command lines that compile the files in the `mm/` directory when I compile the entire kernel, I used those command lines but with my personalised `LLVM` compiler and I generated the entire set of object files for the `mm/` directory. I moved that directory into `build/mm/` directory and I started a top down compile on the kernel - but it looks like it recompiled everything. Any ideas how could I prevent the kernel build system from rebuilding everything ?